# How to store data in Session in MVC Application and schedully insert it into database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, caching

I'm working on a MVC website for displaying products. There's a requirement to keep track of every product that user views and store the log in database.

Because I don't want to hit database every time the page loads, I'm trying to store the log in Application level cache. The question is: how can I schedully dump the data in the cache into database? Is there any framework that has done this for me, or any best practice to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is not designed to host background tasks/jobs, but it's possible to do it, although it won't be 100% reliable.

Create a worker class that contains a timer that fires every X interval and empties the app cache and saves the data to the database. In global.asax, create a handler for `Application_Start` and call the worker class' init method from there.

Also expose a flush method on your worker class that you call from the `Application_Stop` event handlar in global.asax, to make sure you flush any outstanding data before the application shuts down.

Comment: I think this should work for my case. But still sounds like a workaround. Do you know how the scalable website, let's say StackOverflow, handle this problem? Is it a case where the can handle using Redis?

Comment: There seems to be a flaw in this solution.I'm using Quartz as my scheduler. However, it runs in a completely different thread, and couldn't access the Application cache ( in Application state variable).

Comment: I'm sorry. Of course you're right that the Application cache isn't accessible from the background thread. Try storing the `Application` object in a property in your worker class when initializing from `Application_Start`.

Comment: Well, I tried using System.Web.Caching.Cache with the CacheItemRemovedCallback delegate, but that doesn't allow to batch update, so literally, it just delayed the logging action. I'm starting to think that this is not how ASP.NET suppose to work, I'm thinking of 2 solution now: first one is to use Piwik, and the second one is use Flume. I don't know, I'll mark your answer as the correct solution because it's helpful, maybe some singleton object should work, if I can workout the multi-threading part.